# Clarification on Nacha Rules OG97-OG98

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

If there is a process that is separating the debits and credits and allowing them to be sent with different effective dates, that causes an issue in our compliance with the Nacha rules. We want to ensure we understand the full process and why the totals aren't matching as we expect them to.

"The use of Micro-Entries must not result in a net debit to the Receiver’s account, and one or more debit Micro-Entries may not be transmitted without simultaneous transmission, for settlement at the same time, one or more credit Micro-Entries that, in aggregate value, are equal to or greater than the amount of the debit micro-entry(ies). ACH debit Micro-Entries are permitted only in tandem with corresponding ACH credit Micro-Entries.

Because the Rules require simultaneous transmission and settlement of credit Micro-Entries and offsetting debit Micro-Entries, an Originator that transmits a credit Micro-Entry with an offsetting debit Micro-Entry to a Receiver’s account must use the same value in the Effective Entry Date field for each of the Micro-Entries. If the Originator’s process separates the files for debits and credits, those files must be submitted one immediately following the other, as soon as possible, so that the entries may be submitted into the same processing window. A slight difference in submission time (for example, seconds between) can be considered reasonable if the files are submitted close together and allows for the transactions to be submitted to the ACH Operator in the same processing window. The intent of this requirement is to provide credit and offsetting debit Micro-Entries to the RDFI within the same distributed file so that the RDFI can control the impact to the Receiver’s account."

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that kind of question is a bit off-topic in terms of the Banno Digital Toolkit. Your best bet is to create a jSource case which can be routed to the folks who are experts on the topic of your question.